# unable to connect to a localhost server using express generator and mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-generator

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGRHu.png)

database wont be connected and server selection error is showing

i expected the message "database connected" in the console but instead error is shown

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

errno: -4078,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 27017